# In JHipster how to create entity with relationship with User?

Tags: jhipster

I need to create my own entities using the JHipster using the command "yo jhipster:entity myEntity" that have many-to-one relationship with the User entity that comes by default in JHipster.

I have tried unsuccessfully to create in the wizard a relationship with the entity "user" and the field "login" but it is not working.

What is the good way to do this with JHipster? Or do I have to create the entity without JHipster tool (but I need the CRUD!).

Thanks,

Yann

Answer (score 20):

Just an update - jhipster 2.5.0 was released a few days ago adding support for this. Created this answer since the formatting in comments make i pretty hard to read.

When creating a relation for your entity simply answer the questions like this

```
? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? Yes
? What is the name of the other entity? user
? What is the name of the relationship? owner
? What is the type of the relationship? many-to-one
? When you display this relationship with AngularJS, which field from 'user' do you want to use? login
```

Possible values on how to display the relation could be: id, login, first_name, last_name, email

See https://jhipster.github.io/2015/03/01/jhipster-release-2.5.0.html for moreinformation

Comment: Is it possible to use a one-to-many relationship with the user entity ? I'd like to create a 'Company' entity, one company relating to several users. How one would implement that with jhipster ?

Comment: But how to create an relationship from the user entity side? The xml file is not being found because the entity is created within the initial_schema file and is not a standalone entity.

Answer (score 12):

Just to add to the correct answer by @stoffer, if you're using the jdl it will look like:

```
relationship ManyToOne {
    Owner{user(email)} to User{owner(name)}
}
```

Comment: I know that is an old post. The default implementation of the Use class can't be changed by JHipster. That is that User class won't have an attribute "owner" with the JDL.

Answer (score 5):

at a good sample in an official document is say :

```
entity Blog {
    name String required minlength(3),
    handle String required minlength(2)
}

relationship ManyToOne {
    Blog{user(login)} to User 
}
```

[jdl-samples/blog.jh](https://github.com/jhipster/jdl-samples/blob/master/blog.jh)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the 1.x version, this wasn't made to work, so basically you should do it by hand, without the generator (but it is definitely doable).
For the 2.x version, we have refactored the User object to have an ID field -> this should make this a lot easier, but as this is not released yet, we don't have a feedback at the moment.

Comment: Just an update - jhipster 2.5.0 was released a few days ago adding support for this.
When creating a relation simply 

? Do you want to add a relationship to another entity? Yes
? What is the name of the other entity? user
? What is the name of the relationship? owner
? What is the type of the relationship? many-to-one
? When you display this relationship with AngularJS, which field from 'user' do you want to use? login
(possible values here could be; id, login, first_name, last_name, email)

See https://jhipster.github.io/2015/03/01/jhipster-release-2.5.0.html for information

Answer (score 0):

I have come into this issue and solved it by using a simple `one-to-one` relationship first that will extend the user entity, because it is simple and manageable easily and can make the extended entity be the owner of the relationship, then you can create the `many-to-one` relationship with your entity, like this example:

```
entity MyEntity {
  MyField Type
  ...
}

entity ApplicationUser {
  additionalField Type
  ...
}

relationship OneToOne {
  ApplicationUser{internalUser} to User
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  MyEntity{appUser} to ApplicationUser{myEntities}
}
```

For more details and approach refer to this [jHipster page](https://www.jhipster.tech/user-entity/).