# jhipster: How to create a one-to-many relationship with user entity?

Tags: jhipster

I have created my domain using jhipster-uml JDL script.
Now I want to establish a O2M from User to an an existing entity (company).
Is there a way to do that via a JDL script?
The script would need to re-declare every entity the relationship needs. But these are existing entities, is there a switch to direct jhipster-uml to use the existing domain definition without the need to re-declare it again?

I just want to avoid using the Liquibase/Java manual setup.

Answer (score 10):

**In the [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/managing-relationships/)**

> Tip: the User entity
>
> Please note that the User entity, which is handled by JHipster, is
>   specific. **You can do many-to-one relationships** to this entity (a Car
>   can have a many-to-one relationship to a User). This will generate a
>   specific query in your new entity repository, so you can filter your
>   entity on the current security user, which is a common requirement.

It seems only many-to-one relations can be generated with the User entity via the sub-generator. I don't know the UML tool but I guess it just use subgenerators under the hood.

You might need to do the relation manually

See also [In JHipster how to create entity with relationship with User?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879373/in-jhipster-how-to-create-entity-with-relationship-with-user)

Answer (score 1):

I already had such problem, resolved it by creating an additional entity with one-to-one relationship to user, like that:

```
entity Company
entity UserProfile
relationship OneToOne {
  UserProfile{user} to User
}
relationship ManyToOne {
  UserProfile{company} to Company
}
```

hope, this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to add skipServer to your JDL, there's 2 ways of doing it:

```
skipServer all except entity1, entity2
```

This aproach will skip the server-side code of all entities except entity1 and entity2

```
skipServer entity1, entity2
```

And this one will skip the code of only entity1 and entity2.

I reccomend the first one since you can ignore all entities except the ones you are willing to re-generate (User and Company). You may also add skipClient to prevent changes to the front-end (same syntax).

Observations:

```
skipServer all except User
```

This will create the relationship only in User since the code from Company is begin skipped.

Also there's a bug where removing skipServer and skipClient from your JDL don't remove them from .jhipster/entity.json, so you will have to go there and delete the line manually.

Answer (score -1):

How about this: [jdl-snippet](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/#/view/%0Aentity%20Company%20%7B%0A%09name%20String%20required%0A%7D%0Arelationship%20OneToMany%20%7B%0A%09User%7Bcompany%7D%20to%20Company%0A%7D%0A)

```
entity Company {
    name String required
}
relationship OneToMany {
    User{company} to Company
}
```