# Jhipster: How to create relationships with User entity using supplied tools?

Tags: java, jhipster

I am developing an app using the Jhipster. In my domain design I have five relationships with the User entity. I don't understand why the Jhipster does not allow relationships *from* it. I have changed the design so it counts with ManyToOne relationships etc. to avoid changing the User entity, but there is one relationship I cannot change - User is resident of a Flat, Flat has multiple residents.

I can adjust the generated entities and related files by hand, but that can produce problems in the future, when I would like to change the domain and wanted to use the jhipster tools (`jhipster-uml`, `yo jhipster:entity`)

**My question is - is there a way of creating such OneToMany relationship with the pre-generated User entity using supplied jhipster tools?**

I have read the related stackoverflow questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879373/in-jhipster-how-to-create-entity-with-relationship-with-user), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810441/jhipster-how-to-create-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-user-entity)), but that did not help very much.

Jhipster version 3.1.0, jhipster-uml version 1.6.5. My domain design in JDL is avalaible at [GitHub](https://github.com/WhyINeedToFillUsername/bp/blob/master/entities-jdl.jh).

Answer (score 0):

One work-around may be to create a separate object for the relationship, and use the fact that all entities have the "createdBy" attribute.

```
entity Residency {

}

relationship ManyToMany {
    Flat{resident} to Residency{flat(name)}
}
```

Then make the user create a Residency object, manually or automatically on signup or whatever you need.

Now you can search for all Residencies for specific User or all Residents of a specific flat, just by using normal Spring Data queries using createdBy column.